# Integrable Fourier transform implies continuity

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have read the following statement in a number of places  ([here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YfA7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=discontinuous%20function%20cannot%20have%20integrable%20transform&source=bl&ots=rz9wMjpejY&sig=WwM51L-I1P1ZVtKLygwR4pFTgfI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_27r9_P3TAhUJ7hoKHRARAXIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=discontinuous%20function%20cannot%20have%20integrable%20transform&f=false) for example)

> A discontinuous function cannot have an integrable Fourier transform.

The contrapositive of this statement is: if $\hat f$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, then $f$ is continuous. I fail to see why this is true. I know that if $\hat f$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, then $f=\mathcal F^{-1}(\hat f)$ **a.e.** The inverse Fourier transform $\mathcal F^{-1}(\hat f)$ is indeed a continous function, but how can continuity of $f$ be derived ? A discontinuous function may coincide with a continuous function except at a single point...

In a more general setting:

Comment: Elements of $L^1(\mathbb R)$ are equivalence classes of functions, where $f \sim g$ iff $f = g$ a.e. I think the statement is: If  the equivalence class $[f] \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ has no continuous representative, then $\hat f$ cannot be in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @KennyWong: One normally writes just $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and even for example $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ and think of $f$ as a function, and just think of the equivalence class when it's really needed.

Comment: this is circular, no? The Fourier inversion formula is only correct on the level of pointwise equality if we assume continuity of $f$.

Comment: Moreover take $f=\chi_{\Bbb Q}$. This is everywhere discontinuous yet is integrable with integrable Fourier transform.

Comment: The correct statement is: “if $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb C$ is measurable and we have that both $f$ and $\mathcal{F}(f)$ are (Lebesgue) integrable then there is a bounded, continuous function $g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb C$ with $f=g$ **almost everywhere**”. ($g$ will be the inverse Fourier transform of $\mathcal{F}(f)$). That does not mean $f$ itself is (almost) everywhere continuous! As, I now realise, Kenny Wong also pointed out. Imo the accepted answer is wrong/misleading because it already relies on continuity of $f$ to apply the Fourier inversion in that  way, on the level of pointwise equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll abuse notation and write $u(x) \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ for an expression $u(x)$ instead of writing the more correct $x \mapsto u(x) \in L^1(\mathbb R)$

Suppose that $\hat f(\xi) \in L^1(\mathbb R)$. Then also $\hat f(\xi) e^{i \xi x} \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

By the Fourier inversion formula,
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \hat f(\xi) e^{i \xi x} d\xi$$

We want to show that for any $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ we have $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

It's enough to show that $\lim_{x_n \to x_0} f(x_n) = f(x_0)$ for any sequence $x_n \to x_0$.

Let $\hat f_n(\xi) = \hat f(\xi) e^{i \xi x_n}$ and $g(\xi) = |\hat f(\xi)|$. Since $e^{i \xi x}$ is continuous in $x$, we have pointwise convergence, i.e. $\hat f_n(\xi) \to \hat f(\xi)$ for every $\xi \in \mathbb R$. Also, for all $n$, $|\hat f_n(\xi)| \leq g(\xi)$ where $g(\xi) = |\hat f(\xi)| \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

By [the dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) then $\int \lim_{n \to \infty} \hat f_n(\xi) d\xi = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \hat f_n(\xi) d\xi$, i.e.
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \hat f(\xi) e^{i \xi x} d\xi 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \hat f_n(\xi) d\xi
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \hat f(\xi) e^{i \xi x_n} d\xi
= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$$

Thus, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: As @FShrike pointed out, if $f$ and $\mathcal{F}[f]$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then indeed $g:=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}[f]]$ is continuous (see there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) but it only corresponds to $f$ almost everywhere. So your last equation should be $g(x)=...=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)$.

Comment: @Nicolas. True. I should have thought about that when I wrote my answer.